# How to make form field a hyperlink in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have an options array:

```
$allAmazonMatches = Array ( [1] => B002I0HJZO [2] => B002I0HJzz [3] => B002I0HJccccccccc )
```

I display them using a Form helper:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('AmazonMatches', array('action' => 'selectMatches'));
echo $this->Form->input('option_id', array('options' => $allAmazonMatches, 'type' => 'radio'));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));
?>
```

What I want to show is:

```
option1       http://somewebsite/B002I0HJZO (hyper link that opens in new tab)
option2       http://somewebsite/B002I0HJzz (hyper link that opens in new tab)
```

How can I style my options array to do that?

Comment: You want your options to be a select/dropdown field *AND* links at the same time? Do you have an example of how that's supposed to look?

Comment: No just want the options to stay as radio buttons and have the radio button text a hyper link that uses the value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$label1 = $this->Html->link('blabla1', 'http://www.google.de', array('target' => '_blank'));
$label2 = $this->Html->link('blabla2', 'http://www.google.de', array('target' => '_blank'));

$options = array(0 => $label1, 1 => $label2);

echo $this->Form->input('accept', array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => $options));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but I'm not sure it's a recommend practice. Clicking the label should really check the radio box - but if you really have to:

```
    $allAmazonMatches = array(
      'B002I0HJZO' => '<a href="http://somewebsite/B002I0HJZO">http://somewebsite/B002I0HJZO</a>',
      'B002I0HJzz' => '<a href="http://somewebsite/B002I0HJZO">http://somewebsite/B002I0HJzz</a>',
      'B002I0HJccccccccc' => '<a href="http://somewebsite/B002I0HJZO">http://somewebsite/B002I0HJccccccccc</a>'
    );
```